# Good database structure for scenario with orders that have a state and the state has a date

Tags: database-design

so we have a table `orders`

with say:

`id`, `product_id`, `order_state_id`, `comment`

`1, 5, 2, 'thisisatest'`

we have a table `order_state`
with

`id`, `name`

`1, pending processing`

`2, payment accepted`

for each of the order states of an order, i must save a date as of when the state was performed. The order can only be in one state at a time.

say we have an order that gets put into `payment accepted` state. Now I have to save a date/time along with it.

what is the cleanest / best way of doing that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you already put `order_state_id` in your `orders` table why you don't put a `timestamp` or a `datetime` column along with it?

When you update `order_state_id` to the desired state update the timestamp along with it.

If you think that there is a high probability that your status list will expand over time then you may have a need to keep history of status changes for each order. In order to do that you'll need to throw out `order_state_id` and the `timestamp` from `orders` and create an association table like that will link `orders` with `order_state` :

```
orders_state_history
record_id (optional)
order_id  
state_id
timestamp/datetime
```